# How to get data from firebase as non Realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any possibility to get data from firebase as non real-time database? e.g. I want to get data  only once and don't want it to refresh on any change after it.

I went through firebase documentation and found this for my **Kotlin** code.

```
        var database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("profiles")
        database.child(authorId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

            val profile = p0.getValue(Profile::class.java)
            authorTextView.text = profile!!.username

}}
```

But it still keeps on refreshing in real-time and I want to load it only once.

**Edited:** Actually this code is part of onBindViewHolder method in an adapter which is populated by firebase using `addValueEventListener()`. I think it is triggering again and again due to this listener, but how can i avoid this?

Comment: That listener should only fire once.  Are you actually adding it multiple times?  It'll fire each time you add a new one.

Comment: This what this code is actually doing. Can you please share more code, maybe you are adding a new listener in another part of your code as also Doug Stevenson mentioned in his comment and please responde with @.

Comment: Yes you are right. this is being added multiple times. I updated my question

Answer (score -1):

**[JAVA]** After searching without answer, I did that:

```
int wall = 1;
@onCreate...
reference.child(iden).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (wall == 1) {
            wall = 2;
            `enter code here`

        }
```